# JustGage not working properly with Bootstrap on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, justgage

I included JustGage as:

```
var g1 = new JustGage({
              id: "g1", 
              value:32,
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              title: "Country",
              label: "",
              levelColorsGradient: false,

              levelColors: [
                            "#cd0000",
                            "#0066cc",
                            "#006400"
                          ] 
            });
```

I have placed the gage div as:

```
<div id="g1" class="gage span3" style="width:200px;height:160px;"></div>
```

This should render the gage properly on the jsp page, but it is showing as:

[image]

Neither max, min, nor value is visible now. This is working fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

Comment: Publish your css and html code

Comment: This code is fine , I test it and it works  :)